# Using Validation Callback in Kohana 3.2 ORM model

Tags: validation, orm, callback, kohana

> I'm trying to create a custom function to validate multiple fields in kohana 3.2 orm model.
>
> I know that there's a lot of examples showing how to do this from the controller but I want to set it up in the orm model.
>
> I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
       'my_field' => array(
           array(array($this, 'my_function')),
       ),
   );
}

public function my_function(Validation $validation, $my_field)
{
//Some calculation and then return error..
$validation->add_error($my_field, 'my_field_not_valid');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to define params for your custom callback:

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
       'my_field' => array(
           array(array($this, 'my_function'), array(':validation', ':field')),
       ),
   );
}
```

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/validation#binding-variables

PS. Please paste your error/exception text. Usually it already contains correct answer.